# Randomize div tags without any empty spaces

Tags: javascript, html

I want to shuffle my `div`s without any empty spaces. I used JavaScript code to shuffle, but it's not working properly and it sometimes shows empty spaces after reloading the page.

This is my JavaScript code:

```
var cards = $(".random");
for(var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){
    var target = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length -1) + 1;
    var target2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length -1) + 1;
    cards.eq(target).before(cards.eq(target2));
}
```

And this is my sample div tag:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 random" align="center" id="random">
    <div class="thumbnail" id="border">
        <a href="#modal-2" onclick="lockScroll()"><img src="img/findmyfare.jpg" style="width:100%" class="d-block w-100" class="img-fluid"></a>
        <div class="caption offers">
            <a href="#modal-2" onclick="lockScroll()">
                <div class="offer-wrap">
                    <div class="img-wrap" data-backimg="offers-shopping">
                    </div>
                    <div class="title2">
                        <h5 style="text-align:left;padding-left:10px;color:white;">Up to 25% off on flight<br>
                            bookings
                        </h5>
                    </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <h4 style="padding-top:10px; color:#262362;text-align:left;font-size: 125% !important; cursor: pointer;" href="#modal-2" onclick="lockScroll()">findmyfare</h4>
           <p style="text-align:left; cursor: pointer;" class="text2" href="#modal-2">Offer valid from 20 June - 20 July 2017</p><br>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are not really shuffling cards, you are **moving cards away from their original location to a new location**. The result is that the original location becomes empty - and it will stay empty, unless `random()` happens to pick that empty location as a target later on.

This hidden snippet will visualize that (Run it, then press shuffle button):

> ```js
> function shuffle() {
>   var cards = $(".random");
>   for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
>     var target = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length - 1) + 1;
>     var target2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length - 1) + 1;
>     cards.eq(target).before(cards.eq(target2));
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
> [<span class="random">A</span>]
> [<span class="random">B</span>]
> [<span class="random">C</span>]
> [<span class="random">D</span>]
> [<span class="random">E</span>]
> [<span class="random">F</span>]
> [<span class="random">G</span>]
> [<span class="random">H</span>]
> <br/>
> <button onclick="shuffle()">shuffle</button>
> ```

You can improve this by distinguishing the **locations** from the **cards** themselves, and then by doing an actual **card swap** so locations will always contain exactly one card.

With the new approach the index calculations need to be different, so I changed that too.

Improved snippet:

```js
function shuffle() {
  var cards = $(".random");
  for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    var index1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);
    var index2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);
    var card1 = cards.eq(index1);
    var card2 = cards.eq(index2);
    var location1 = card1.closest(".location");
    var location2 = card2.closest(".location");
    location1.append(card2);
    location2.append(card1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
[<span class="location"><span class="random">A</span></span>]
[<span class="location"><span class="random">B</span></span>]
[<span class="location"><span class="random">C</span></span>]
[<span class="location"><span class="random">D</span></span>]
[<span class="location"><span class="random">E</span></span>]
[<span class="location"><span class="random">F</span></span>]
[<span class="location"><span class="random">G</span></span>]
[<span class="location"><span class="random">H</span></span>]
<br/>
<button onclick="shuffle()">shuffle</button>
```

Comment: i used div elemets. how to add your code into div tags

Comment: <div class"random"></div>

Comment: this is my sample div tag.

Comment: i mention my div tags in my question and how to add your code into my html

Comment: Whether we use `div` or `span` is irrelevant because we select elements by their class names (`$(".random")` and `.closest(".location")`), without using the tag name. You will need to determine where to add the `location` css class, or change the js code to use an existing css class that identifies your "location" elements.

Comment: thanks for helping

Comment: can i identify division id when random

Comment: Such a follow-up should be done using a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: i made a new question. this is link  {https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50809279/how-to-shuffle-div-thumbnails-and-identify-div-id}

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 steps

1) list all cards in all cells

2) start to shuffle them by replace logic (take one random card take another and replace one with another)

in that case you will not have any empty space, and you can control hardness of shuffle by defining for loop count

Comment: can you show me the code

Comment: You have to provide your html also so i will be able to update answer, also would be good to see some screenshot with your wrong result